# Spliting a string after 7th space in java

Tags: java, split

I have a

```
String data =
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 aime1 svrtech 83338 Apr 2 10:26 sat.log -rw-rw-r--+ 1 aime1 svrtech 2435 Apr 2 10:48 MAT.log -rw-rw-r--+ 1 aime1 svrtech 3470 Apr 2 08:35 ant_build.log
```

I want to split this as following and want to store in `ArrayList`

```
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 aime1 svrtech 83338 Apr 2 10:26 sat.log 

-rw-rw-r--+ 1 aime1 svrtech 2435 Apr 2 10:48 MAT.log

-rw-rw-r--+ 1 aime1 svrtech 3470 Apr 2 08:35 ant_build.log
```

I thought of using split function. How do i split on 7th space.
Anyone having idea how to do that.

Comment: is there any reason not to split by all spaces like done with data.split(" ")?

Comment: Why not split on all spaces, wrap the resulting array in a list, take a sublist right of element 7, and join on space?

Comment: Thanks for all the solution, one more thing i have some .txt file also in the string and how to ignore that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`String#split`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) takes the regex as the arguments,so try with something like this

```
String data ="-rw-rw-r--+ 1 aime1 svrtech 83338 Apr 2 10:26 sat.log -rw-rw-r--+ 1 aime1 svrtech 2435 Apr 2 10:48 MAT.log -rw-rw-r--+ 1 aime1 svrtech 3470 Apr 2 08:35 ant_build.log";

    String arr[]=data.split("(?<=.log )");
    for(String s:arr){
    System.out.println(s);
    }
```

Comment: ignore means you need to split using .txt or to remove the .txt ?

Comment: i don't want to save these string into array -rw-rw-r--+ 1 aime1 svrtech 54761 Apr 2 09:43 diff.txt

Answer (score 1):

With the help of regex

```
Patter p = Pattern.complie("-rw.*log");// capture string from  -rw to log
Matcher m = p.matcher("String data= -rw-rw-r--+ 1 aime1 svrtech 83338 Apr 2 10:26 sat.log -rw-rw-r--+ 1 aime1 svrtech 2435 Apr 2 10:48 MAT.log -rw-rw-r--+ 1 aime1 svrtech 3470 Apr 2 08:35 ant_build.log");

while(m.find){
     list.add(m.group()); // list --> ArrayList
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String sData = "-rw-rw-r--+ 1 aime1 svrtech 83338 Apr 2 10:26 sat.log -rw-rw-r--+ 1 aime1 svrtech 2435 Apr 2 10:48 MAT.log -rw-rw-r--+ 1 aime1 svrtech 3470 Apr 2 08:35 ant_build.log ";
    String arrData[] = sData.split(" ");
    int iCounter = 0;

    while(iCounter < arrData.length) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            System.out.print(arrData[iCounter]+"\t");
            iCounter++;
        }
        System.out.println("");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems .log ends your every wanted string. So perhaps you can do it

```
String[] output = input.split(".log ");
```

now every output string will contains the name of the file (except .log). so you can add `.log` to them and use those.

Answer (score 0):

Try with This Code

package pack;

```
public class splitstring {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String data = "-rw-rw-r--+ 1 aime1 svrtech 83338 Apr 2 10:26 sat.log -rw-rw-r--+ 1 aime1 svrtech";
        String[] dataArr = data.split(" ");
        String[] resArr = new String[20];
        int j = 0;
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < dataArr.length; i++) {
            if(j==8){
                resArr[k] = resArr[k]+dataArr[i];
                k++;
                j=0;
                return;
            }
            resArr[k] = resArr[k]+dataArr[i]+" ";
        }
    }
}
```